# getElementByID when script is external

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to access a asp:panel in an external script to make it not visible,but it does not seem to be working. When the Script is in the .aspx file it works fine though.Any suggestions?

In the .aspx file

```
  <script src="App_Themes/custom.js"></script>
  <asp:Button ID="descriptionButton" Text="Description" runat="server" OnClientClick="descButton(); return false;" />

 <asp:Panel ID="desciptionPanel" runat="server"> 
          ///random stuff
               <asp:panel>
```

in the custom.js file

```
function descButton() {

var desc = document.getElementById('<%=desciptionPanel.ClientID%>'); 
desc.style.visibility = "visible";
desc.style.height = "800px";

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `<%=desciptionPanel.ClientID%>` - it is asp.net instruction, not js one, it can work only in aspx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it to two.

First, in the aspx at the server, leave the ID so that you can reuse it later

```
<script>
   window.panelID = '<%= whatever.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

Then, in an external script, just use the ID

```
function externalJSfunction() {

   var desc = document.getElementById(window.panelID);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameter to your function

```
OnClientClick="descButton('<%=desciptionPanel.ClientID%>');
```

then script will be

```
function descButton(id) {
    var desc = document.getElementById(id); 
    desc.style.visibility = "visible";
    desc.style.height = "800px";
}
```